# iPhone : App crashes while displaying print option from UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app I am displaying Print option from `UIButton` using following code.

```
    UIPrintInfo* printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = NSLocalizedString(@"Offerings", @"");


    UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *formatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:@"Share"];
    formatter.startPage = 0;


    CGFloat margin = 72.0f * 0.1f;
    formatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(margin, margin, margin, margin);


    UIPrintInteractionController* pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    pic.delegate = self;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    pic.printFormatter = formatter;
    [formatter release];

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController*, BOOL, NSError*) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController* printController, BOOL completed, NSError* error)
    {
        if (!completed && error)
        {
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Printing Error", @"")
                                  message:[error localizedDescription]
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    };
```

I have tried following options.

```
    [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

OR

```
    [pic presentFromRect:CGRectMake(btnPrint.frame.origin.x, btnPrint.frame.origin.y, btnPrint.frame.size.width, btnPrint.frame.size.height) inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

But it crashes with error : `EXE_BAD_ACCESS`

But when I tried following code for displaying print option, It works fine.

```
  [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Now, I am not using navigation controller. So I can't use this above method.

What should I do ?

Comment: More code please? The whole method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have solved my problem.

The `view` where you are going to give `print` option. It should be contain `navigation controller`.

So, My solution

```
First *first = [[First alloc] initWithNibName:@"First"];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootView:@"first"];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Its strange solution. but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use: `[self presentViewController: animated: completion:];`?

Comment: for printing we have to use object of `UIPrintInteractionController` which is `pic`. And it contains only above three methods. Which will handle other things like `Printer selection` , `Number of pages` and etc.

Comment: Ok, so I'll assume that you have `UIPrintInteractionController *pic;` somewhere in your .h file. But before you try any of these methods, do you have `pic = [[UIPrintInteractionController alloc] init];`?

Comment: No it just required `sharedPrintController` which I have done in this same coding. See its available in question

Comment: Try changing that line to: `UIPrintInteractionController* pic = [[[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController] alloc] init];`

Comment: Hit escape with your cursor right past init and take a loot at the init methods. There are plenty.

Comment: Nop. I didnt find any except `init`. Other methods are not useful for solving this problem.

Comment: I tried only `init` but my bad luck I got `-[UIPrintInteractionController init] not allowed` !!!